# JSTL Date format issue while using <c:import>

Tags: java, jsp, date, jstl, jsp-tags

I have two jsp pages that are hosted in different applications within same tomcat container.

1.jsp

```
<c:import url="http://hostname:9090/application/index/2.jsp">
        <c:param name="city" value="Dubai"/>
</c:import>
```

2.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" scope="page" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" pattern="MM.dd.yyyy" />
```

while accessing 2.jsp directly using http://hostname:9090/application/index/2.jsp is showing date in desired format mentioned in pattern `01.24.2015`

while importing 2.jsp inside of page 1.jsp its showing result 
`"Sat Jan 24 00:26:53 GST 2015 "`

Help me to understand the reason for this strange behavior,
I tried using `scope="request"` but it did not helped either.

Looking forward for reason for this behavior and Solution as well. :)

Comment: Can anybody help me to understand problem in above situation?

Answer (score 1):

```
<%--one.jsp--%>

<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:import url="two.jsp">
    <c:param name="city" value="Dubai"/>
</c:import>

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

<%--two.jsp--%>

<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" scope="page" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" pattern="MM.dd.yyyy" />
```

Comment: fmt tag is also included, in 2.jsp,